# Javascript Map Function Not Storing Correct Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling

My application is just a simple checklist looking like this

[image: screenshot of checklist]

I'm getting some weird behavior with the map function in reactJS.

```js
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"
import todosData from "./data/todosData.js"
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem.js"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(id) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedItems = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
                console.log(todo)
                return todo
            })
            console.log(updatedItems)
            return {
                todos: updatedItems
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => < TodoItem item = {
                item
            }
            key = {
                item.id
            }
            handleClick = {
                this.handleClick
            } />) 

            return ( 
              <div> 
                { todoItems } 
              </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default App
```

Whenever I print out to check if the value did indeed change with console.log(todo.completed) it prints out the correct value in the console, but then I try to print out the entire list of objects and suddenly its back to what it was. In this case I clicked option one

[image: Screen Shot of Console when first item is clicked]

And this is the result when I print out the const updatedItems

[image: console printing out updatedItems]

I can change any other attribute without any trouble, I can even set

```js
todo.completed = false
```

And it will change any checkbox that are checked to unchecked, its only when I try to assign it value using the opposite of its already stored value that the map function doesn't work correctly

Here is the file I'm getting the data from if that helps

```js
const todosData = [{
        id: 1,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Clean gecko tank",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Mow lawn",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
        completed: false
    }
]

export default todosData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue - State Mutation!!

You are mutating your state object when you toggle the completed status.

```
handleClick(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedItems = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed; // <-- state mutation!!
      }
      return todo;
    });
    return {
      todos: updatedItems,
    };
  })
}
```

## Solution

Not only do you need to shallow copy the array that is being updated, you need to also shallow copy all nested objects you intend to update as well so they are no longer shallow equal.

```
handleClick(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedItems = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        return {
          ...todo, // <-- copy into new object reference
          completed: !todo.completed, // <-- set new property value
        };
      }
      return todo;
    });
    return {
      todos: updatedItems,
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll keep my eye on that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleClick(id){
this.setState(prevState => {
  const updatedItems = prevState.todos.map(todo =>{
    if(todo.id === id){
      todo.completed = !todo.completed
    }
    console.log(todo)
    return todo
  },()=>{
        console.log(updatedItems)
   })
  return{
    todos: updatedItems
  }

})
}
```

Please try this once. You might get updated items in console